# Node with Laravel Echo and Socket.io but no response

Tags: node.js, laravel, socket.io, laravel-echo, laravel-broadcast

I am setting up Laravel API for a mobile app to call the APIs and I am currently configuring Laravel Broadcast which I am new to it. I have installed laravel-echo-server and redis for the server side while laravel-echo and socket.io-client for the client side.

As you can see, in the screenshot below, the client is subscribed to the channel.

[image]

Here is my code

**OrderController.php**

```
broadcast(new Ordered(Order::find($order->id)));
```

**OrderEvent.php**

```
public function broadcastOn()
{
     return new Channel('order');
}
```

**channels.php**

```
Broadcast::channel('order.{orderId}', function (User $user, int $orderId) {
    return true;
});
```

I tried to run `node index.js` in the terminal with the following codes in my index.js and there's no response from the console.log:

**index.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const Echo = require('laravel-echo');
const io = require('socket.io-client');

const echo = new Echo({
  broadcaster: 'socket.io',
  host: 'http://192.168.1.14:6001',
  client: io,
});

echo.channel('public').listen('order', (e) => {
  console.log("DATA RECEIVED");
  console.log(e);
})
```

Comment: What interfaces does your event implement?

Comment: Secondly, you are listening on the `public` channel, although you said to broadcast it on the `Channel('order');`

Comment: i have changed 
`echo.channel('public').listen('order', (e) => {
  console.log("DATA RECEIVED");
  console.log(e);
})` to channel order and the listener of name Ordered
The client joined order channel but the Ordered listener seems like not working

Comment: may i know how to do the debugging here? as there's no console.log result showing out and there's no event listener of name Ordered shown in the command too.

Comment: Ok I'll answer in a bit, but I do need to see your event class `Ordered`.

Comment: I have added a BroadcastAs in the Ordered event listener class and call it in my client side and it works well now. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: That's why I needed to see your event class :D